# C# LINQ returning value from parent node in xml

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xml-parsing

I am trying to simplify the following code. It works fine, but I would like to refactor it with LINQ.

I was only able to work it out using 2 separate queries to and two separate arrays:

```
var testid = xliff.Descendants()
                  .Elements(xmlns + "trans-unit")
                  .Elements(xmlns + "seg-source")
                  .Elements(xmlns + "mrk")
                  .Where(e => e.Attribute("mtype").Value == "seg").ToArray();

string[] parentids = new string[testid.Length];
int counter = 0;
foreach (var item in testid)
{
    XElement testelement = item.Parent.Parent.PreviousNode as XElement;
    parentids[counter] = testelement.Elements(xmlns + "source")
                                    .Elements(xmlns + "x")
                                    .LastOrDefault()
                                    .Attribute("id")
                                    .Value.ToString();
    counter++;
}
```

Updated code:

```
var parentids = xliff.Descendants()
                     .Elements(xmlns + "trans-unit")
                     .Elements(xmlns + "seg-source")
                     .Elements(xmlns + "mrk")
                     .Where(e => e.Attribute("mtype").Value == "seg")
                     .Select(item => (XElement)item.Parent.Parent.PreviousNode)
                     .Where(item => item != null)
                     .Select(item => item.Elements(xmlns + "source")
                     .Where(itema => itema != null)
                     .Select(itemb => itemb.Elements(xmlns + "x")             
                     .LastOrDefault()
                     .Attribute("id")
                     .Value.ToString())).ToArray();
```

I would like to see if this can be solved with one LINQ query. Thanks.

**Update:** A sample part of the xliff I am trying to parse:

Here is the snippet of the XML so you see what I am trying to get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xliff xmlns:sdl="http://sdl.com/FileTypes/SdlXliff/1.0" version="1.2" sdl:version="1.0" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
<!-- xliff goes on here -->
  <trans-unit id="495bbe35-ad63-4d37-91e0-8261c2e4052e" translate="no">
    <source>
      <x id="11" />
      <x id="12" />       <!-- THIS IS THE ID I WANT TO GET PARSED -->
    </source>
  </trans-unit>
  <trans-unit id="5bccf5f4-56c9-4969-8416-f3114eb36e86">
    <source>
      <x id="13" />SOME TEXT
    </source>
    <seg-source>
      <mrk mtype="seg" mid="6">     <!-- THIS IS THE 'MID' I WANT TO START FROM -->
        <x id="13" />SOME TEXT
      </mrk>
    </seg-source>
    <target>
      <mrk mtype="seg" mid="6">
        <x id="13" />SOME TRANSLATION
      </mrk>
    </target>
    <sdl:seg-defs>
      <sdl:seg id="6" conf="ApprovedTranslation" origin="interactive" />
    </sdl:seg-defs>
  </trans-unit>
```

**Update:**

XMLtype2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><xliff xmlns:sdl="http://sdl.com/FileTypes/SdlXliff/1.0" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2" version="1.2" sdl:version="1.0"><file original="C:\Users\talentbi\AppData\Local\Temp\88f49a09-41ef-4777-ab1e-931fed467885\4D_Kit_Intro_2015_Updates_hu_HU_20151209_153539\hu-HU\Internet_Anti-DrugIntro2015.xml_1457007.xlf" datatype="x-sdlfilterframework2" source-language="en-US" target-language="hu-HU"><body><trans-unit translate="no" id="c3a13bfb-ed51-49cf-8278-e2c86c2114c0"><source><x id="0"/></source></trans-unit><group><sdl:cxts><sdl:cxt id="1"/></sdl:cxts><trans-unit id="3b4520df-4483-4c9e-8a9b-ce2544269f3e"><source><x id="1"/>Drugs are robbing our children of their future. <x id="2"/>Every 17 seconds a teenager experiments with an illicit drug for the first time. <x id="3"/>And nearly half meet dealers right in the hallways and campuses of their schools. <x id="4"/>While at the same time prescription drug abuse has soared by 400%, <x id="5"/>exceeding heroin, cocaine and Ecstasy combined. <x id="6"/>Billions are spent on programs to reach kids, <x id="7"/>with little or no impact on teen experimentation. <x id="8"/>And all while drug-related crime and violence among young people <x id="9"/>continues to escalate, threatening their lives and the safety of their communities. <x id="10"/>But helping young people lead lives without drugs <x id="11"/>is the Foundation for a Drug-Free World, <x id="12"/>coordinating the largest non-governmental <x id="13"/>drug education and prevention campaign on Earth. <x id="14"/>Drawing on more than 25 years of experience in drug prevention, <x id="15"/>today Foundation volunteers and members of like-minded organizations <x id="16"/>conduct an international multi-media Truth About Drugs campaign. <x id="17"/>At the heart of the program is a series of high-impact educational booklets <x id="18"/>covering the most commonly abused drugs, <x id="19"/>educating youth so they can make their own decision about drugs. <x id="20"/>And as the materials are available in some 20 languages, <x id="21"/>Drug-Free World teams work everywhere – <x id="22"/>from cocaine distribution points in Southern Florida <x id="23"/>to neighborhoods overrun with meth in Southern California. <x id="24"/>From the crack streets of New York and Harlem <x id="25"/>to designer-drug routes of Australia and Asia <x id="26"/>and out to the cannabis trafficking lanes of Africa and Western Europe. <x id="27"/>Then there are the partnerships the Foundation forges everywhere else. <x id="28"/>The New York Drug-Free World formed an alliance <x id="29"/>with the New York City Department of Youth and Community Development, <x id="30"/>linking them to hundreds of schools and over a million students across New York City – <x id="31"/>from Brooklyn and the Bronx to Staten Island and Manhattan. <x id="32"/>All of which led to Drug-Free World being officially inaugurated into <x id="33"/>a New York State Senate Task Force on Prescription Drugs and Heroin – <x id="34"/>and this from the New York State Senate: <x id="35"/>“Drug-Free World has enriched our state and is worthy of the esteem of all New Yorkers.” <x id="36"/>In Indonesia, Drug-Free World Southeast Asia advances Truth About Drugs to Indonesian youth <x id="37"/>through the National Scouting Association and its membership of more than 20 million kids. <x id="38"/>Partnering with the Association’s Director for Education and Training, <x id="39"/>Drug-Free World provided 550,000 translated Truth About Drugs booklets, <x id="40"/>as well as documentaries, educator guides and lesson plans. <x id="41"/>Directly following this, more than 4,000 Senior Scout Trainers adopted Drug-Free World <x id="42"/>to simultaneously attack the plague of drug abuse in Indonesia and serve as agents of change for the nation. <x id="43"/>In Mexico City, Drug-Free World partners <x id="44"/>with the Auxiliary Security Forces for the State of Mexico, <x id="45"/>receiving more than 4,000 booklets pertaining to the principal drugs in their territory. <x id="46"/>They in turn deploy with precision, distributing literal truckloads of booklets all over the city <x id="47"/>which is how Drug-Free World infused nearly a quarter of a million booklets <x id="48"/>and thereby assisted the State of Mexico in a war against drugs. <x id="49"/>Booklet distribution is flanked by a series <x id="50"/>of award-winning public service announcements <x id="51"/>broadcast on hundreds of TV stations, <x id="52"/>totaling over 120 countries and reaching tens of millions of viewers. <x id="53"/>But the one component that distinguishes Drug-Free World <x id="54"/>from any other similarly aimed program is this one. <x id="55"/>An award-winning, full-length, hour-and-a-half documentary <x id="56"/>containing films on every drug of choice. <x id="57"/>This documentary educates and enlightens and speaks to kids in their own language. <x id="58"/>It’s told by people who know addiction firsthand and have actually “been there,” <x id="59"/>and by telling their stories they pass on what they learned <x id="60"/>so others can avoid going down the same path. <x id="61"/>Drug-Free World also provides the Truth About Drugs Education Package. <x id="62"/>It’s complete with posters, the documentary and PSAs, an educational guide, <x id="63"/>two dozen sets of the booklets – in other words, an entire curriculum <x id="64"/>with a teacher’s manual, a full semester of lesson plans, <x id="65"/>essays and homework assignments. <x id="66"/>And all of this is provided by the Foundation at no charge to educators. <x id="67"/>While to ensure the Truth About Drugs reaches everyone, <x id="68"/>there is drugfreeworld.org. <x id="69"/>When visitors arrive there, <x id="70"/>they discover the ultimate interactive drug resource center for educators, adults and kids. <x id="71"/>Here anyone can view and download the booklets, watch films and PSAs, <x id="72"/>create a virtual classroom or download the curriculum app <x id="73"/>and order resources to take the program even further. <x id="74"/>All told, it adds up to more than 72 million Truth About Drugs booklets distributed, <x id="75"/>tens of thousands of drug awareness events in 70 countries, <x id="76"/>some 2,000 alliances with other drug prevention entities, <x id="77"/>more than 17 million visits annually to the Drug-Free World website <x id="78"/>and hundreds ordering materials every week – <x id="79"/>bringing the total people reached with the Foundation’s drug-free message <x id="80"/>to more than 200 million in a single year. <x id="81"/>It <x id="82"/>is<x id="83"/> possible to reverse the trend of drug abuse in our society. <x id="84"/>The results of the Truth About Drugs program have been proven <x id="85"/>to effectively empower youth so they make the right choice. <x id="86"/>Anyone can help by supporting a Truth About Drugs program, <x id="87"/>or providing for distribution of educational materials <x id="88"/>to youth in their community or city. <x id="89"/>By joining the Foundation for a Drug-Free World’s campaign, <x id="90"/>we can help steer an entire generation away from drugs <x id="91"/>and set them on course for a drug-free future. </source><seg-source><mrk mtype="seg" mid="2"><x id="1"/>Drugs are robbing our children of their future. </mrk><mrk mtype="seg" mid="3"><x id="2"/>Every 17 seconds a teenager experiments with an illicit drug for the first time. </mrk><mrk mtype="seg" mid="4"><x id="3"/>And nearly half meet dealers right in the hallways and campuses of their schools. </mrk><mrk mtype="seg" mid="5"><x id="4"/>While at the same time prescription drug abuse has soared by 400%, <x id="5"/>exceeding heroin, cocaine and Ecstasy combined. </mrk><mrk mtype="seg" mid="6"><x id="6"/>Billions are spent on programs to reach kids, <x id="7"/>with little or no impact on teen experimentation. </mrk><mrk mtype="seg" mid="7"><x id="8"/>And all while drug-related crime and violence among young people <x id="9"/>continues to escalate, threatening their lives and the safety of their communities. </mrk><mrk mtype="seg" mid="8"><x id="10"/>But helping young people lead lives without drugs <x id="11"/>is the Foundation for a Drug-Free World, <x id="12"/>coordinating the largest non-governmental <x id="13"/>drug education and prevention campaign on Earth. </mrk><mrk mtype="seg" mid="9"><x id="14"/>Drawing on more than 25 years of experience in drug prevention, <x id="15"/>today Foundation volunteers and members of like-minded organizations <x id="16"/>conduct an international multi-media Truth About Drugs campaign. </mrk><mrk mtype="seg" mid="10"><x id="17"/>At the heart of the program is a series of high-impact educational booklets <x id="18"/>covering the most commonly abused drugs, <x id="19"/>educating youth so they can make their own decision about drugs. </mrk><mrk mtype="seg" mid="11"><x id="20"/>And as the materials are available in some 20 languages, <x id="21"/>Drug-Free World teams work everywhere – <x id="22"/>from cocaine distribution points in Southern Florida <x id="23"/>to neighborhoods overrun with meth in Southern California. </mrk><mrk mtype="seg" mid="12"><x id="24"/>From the crack streets of New York and Harlem <x id="25"/>to designer-drug routes of Australia and Asia <x id="26"/>and out to the cannabis trafficking lanes of Africa and Western Europe. </mrk><mrk mtype="seg" mid="13"><x id="27"/>Then there are the partnerships the Foundation forges everywhere else. </mrk><mrk mtype="seg" mid="14"><x id="28"/>The New York Drug-Free World formed an alliance <x id="29"/>with the New York City Department of Youth and Community Development, <x id="30"/>linking them to hundreds of schools and over a million students across New York City – <x id="31"/>from Brooklyn and the Bronx to Staten Island and Manhattan. </mrk><mrk mtype="seg" mid="15"><x id="32"/>All of which led to Drug-Free World being officially inaugurated into <x id="33"/>a New York State Senate Task Force on Prescription Drugs and Heroin – <x id="34"/>and this from the New York State Senate: <x id="35"/>“Drug-Free World has enriched our state and is worthy of the esteem of all New Yorkers.” </mrk><mrk mtype="seg" mid="16"><x id="36"/>In Indonesia, Drug-Free World Southeast Asia advances Truth About Drugs to Indonesian youth <x id="37"/>through the National Scouting Association and its membership of more than 20 million kids. </mrk><mrk mtype="seg" mid="17"><x id="38"/>Partnering with the Association’s Director for Education and Training, <x id="39"/>Drug-Free World provided 550,000 translated Truth About Drugs booklets, <x id="40"/>as well as documentaries, educator guides and lesson plans. </mrk><mrk mtype="seg" mid="18"><x id="41"/>Directly following this, more than 4,000 Senior Scout Trainers adopted Drug-Free World <x id="42"/>to simultaneously attack the plague of drug abuse in Indonesia and serve as agents of change for the nation. </mrk><mrk mtype="seg" mid="19"><x id="43"/>In Mexico City, Drug-Free World partners <x id="44"/>with the Auxiliary Security Forces for the State of Mexico, <x id="45"/>receiving more than 4,000 booklets pertaining to the principal drugs in their territory. </mrk><mrk mtype="seg" mid="20"><x id="46"/>They in turn deploy with precision, distributing literal truckloads of booklets all over the city <x id="47"/>which is how Drug-Free World infused nearly a quarter of a million booklets <x id="48"/>and thereby assisted the State of Mexico in a war against drugs. </mrk><mrk mtype="seg" mid="21"><x id="49"/>Booklet distribution is flanked by a series <x id="50"/>of award-winning public service announcements <x id="51"/>broadcast on hundreds of TV stations, <x id="52"/>totaling over 120 countries and reaching tens of millions of viewers. </mrk><mrk mtype="seg" mid="22"><x id="53"/>But the one component that distinguishes Drug-Free World <x id="54"/>from any other similarly aimed program is this one. </mrk><mrk mtype="seg" mid="23"><x id="55"/>An award-winning, full-length, hour-and-a-half documentary <x id="56"/>containing films on every drug of choice. </mrk><mrk mtype="seg" mid="24"><x id="57"/>This documentary educates and enlightens and speaks to kids in their own language. </mrk><mrk mtype="seg" mid="25"><x id="58"/>It’s told by people who know addiction firsthand and have actually “been there,” <x id="59"/>and by telling their stories they pass on what they learned <x id="60"/>so others can avoid going down the same path. </mrk><mrk mtype="seg" mid="26"><x id="61"/>Drug-Free World also provides the Truth About Drugs Education Package. </mrk><mrk mtype="seg" mid="27"><x id="62"/>It’s complete with posters, the documentary and PSAs, an educational guide, <x id="63"/>two dozen sets of the booklets – in other words, an entire curriculum <x id="64"/>with a teacher’s manual, a full semester of lesson plans, <x id="65"/>essays and homework assignments. </mrk><mrk mtype="seg" mid="28"><x id="66"/>And all of this is provided by the Foundation at no charge to educators. </mrk><mrk mtype="seg" mid="29"><x id="67"/>While to ensure the Truth About Drugs reaches everyone, <x id="68"/>there is drugfreeworld.org. </mrk><mrk mtype="seg" mid="30"><x id="69"/>When visitors arrive there, <x id="70"/>they discover the ultimate interactive drug resource center for educators, adults and kids. </mrk><mrk mtype="seg" mid="31"><x id="71"/>Here anyone can view and download the booklets, watch films and PSAs, <x id="72"/>create a virtual classroom or download the curriculum app <x id="73"/>and order resources to take the program even further. </mrk><mrk mtype="seg" mid="32"><x id="74"/>All told, it adds up to more than 72 million Truth About Drugs booklets distributed, <x id="75"/>tens of thousands of drug awareness events in 70 countries, <x id="76"/>some 2,000 alliances with other drug prevention entities, <x id="77"/>more than 17 million visits annually to the Drug-Free World website <x id="78"/>and hundreds ordering materials every week – <x id="79"/>bringing the total people reached with the Foundation’s drug-free message <x id="80"/>to more than 200 million in a single year. </mrk><mrk mtype="seg" mid="33"><x id="81"/>It <x id="82"/>is<x id="83"/> possible to reverse the trend of drug abuse in our society. </mrk><mrk mtype="seg" mid="34"><x id="84"/>The results of the Truth About Drugs program have been proven <x id="85"/>to effectively empower youth so they make the right choice. </mrk><mrk mtype="seg" mid="35"><x id="86"/>Anyone can help by supporting a Truth About Drugs program, <x id="87"/>or providing for distribution of educational materials <x id="88"/>to youth in their community or city. </mrk><mrk mtype="seg" mid="36"><x id="89"/>By joining the Foundation for a Drug-Free World’s campaign, <x id="90"/>we can help steer an entire generation away from drugs <x id="91"/>and set them on course for a drug-free future. </mrk></seg-source><target></target></trans-unit></group><trans-unit translate="no" id="7890462c-edcb-4fe6-9192-033ba76d9942"><source><x id="183"/></source></trans-unit></body></file></xliff>
```

Comment: please post a simplified XML sample

Comment: @har07 -- I posted a sample XML, sorry for the delay here

Comment: ah I see, check out the latest update of my answer

Comment: How many trans-unit tags do you have?  Is there any other tags that can be used to extract data.  It is extremely unusual to have to use "PreviousNode".  There should be a better way to simplify code, but i can't tell with the small sample posted.

Comment: @jdweng -- It is totally random. The only consistent pattern is that the data is contained in the previous `trans-unit` which does not have a `trans` child, because this segment only contains markup. This is the sdlxliff approach at least. The only other way to get this datum that I can see is that all those tags that are in such markup segments are all in the header encapsulated in `st` tags. The `id`s are sequential. But I the other approach is easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this

```
string[] parentids = xliff.Descendants()
    .Elements(xmlns + "trans-unit")
    .Elements(xmlns + "seg-source")
    .Elements(xmlns + "mrk")
    .Where(e => e.Attribute("mtype").Value == "seg")
    .Select(item => (XElement)item.Parent.Parent.PreviousNode)
        .Where(item => item != null)
        .Select(item => item.Elements(xmlns + "source")
        .Elements(xmlns + "x")
        .LastOrDefault()
        .Attribute("id")
        .Value.ToString()).ToArray();
```

Comment: Hmm. This `Where` gives a compiler error: 'System.Xml.Linq.XElement' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and no extension method 'Where' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Xml.Linq.XElement' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: And what should i return, if previous node is <group> ?

Comment: Thanks, please see my new post: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36927046/c-sharp-linq-xml-parsing-using-previousnode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36927046/c-sharp-linq-xml-parsing-using-previousnode)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way :

```
var parentids = xliff.Descendants()
                     .Elements(xmlns + "trans-unit")
                     .Where(o => o.Elements(xmlns + "seg-source")
                                  .Elements(xmlns + "mrk")
                                  .Any(e => (string)e.Attribute("mtype") == "seg"))
                     .Select(o => (XElement)o.PreviousNode)
                     .Elements(xmlns + "source")
                     .Elements(xmlns + "x")
                     .Select(o => (string)o.Attribute("id"));
```

Comment: Thanks. I added a sample xml now. The previous node is another `trans-unit` (the previous node of the parent of parent).

Comment: thanks for the update. Aha! this now returns an array of 3 items (I had to add a `ToArray` at the end otherwise it gave me a compile error. But really there are 16 `mrk` with `seg` attribute, so it should give me a 16 length array. You know what? I paste the full XML, just to shorten the pain here. This may help to solve the impasse. (it will be unformatted).

Comment: Can you share the XML somewhere (gist, pastebin, etc)?

Comment: @ib11 According to the latest XML, there are 16 `mrk` with `seg` attributes, but the previous `trans-unit` only contains 3 `x` elements, so the result supposed to be 3 items..

Comment: Thanks, please see my new post: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36927046/c-sharp-linq-xml-parsing-using-previousnode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36927046/c-sharp-linq-xml-parsing-using-previousnode)

Answer (score 0):

I don't like previous, real ugly.  Try this where you don't get any nulls.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            XElement xliff = (XElement)doc.FirstNode;
            XNamespace ns = xliff.Name.Namespace;
            var testid = xliff.Descendants(ns + "trans-unit").Where((x, i) => (i % 2) == 0).Select(y => new {
                   x = y.Descendants(ns + "x")
                   .Select(z => z.Attribute("id").Value)
                   .Last()
            }).ToList();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, could you help me and point me to where can I study up on what does this `Where` expression mean? Also, please see my new post: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36927046/c-sharp-linq-xml-parsing-using-previousnode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36927046/c-sharp-linq-xml-parsing-using-previousnode)

Comment: I usually use this webpage : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b.  The (x,i) can be used with Select or Where and x is same as normal select/where and i is the index like in a for loop.

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot! I guess you have seen me other post since... I see if I can build your suggestion in there. (For now I test the XML first to see which version and then execute either one of the 2 type of queries.)

Comment: Thanks, I am trying to find the meaning of %. What is that one?