# C# LINQ xml parsing using "PreviousNode"

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xml-parsing

With quite some help from SO, I managed to put together the following LINQ expression.

```
var parentids = xliff.Descendants()
                     .Elements(xmlns + "trans-unit")
                     .Elements(xmlns + "seg-source")
                     .Elements(xmlns + "mrk")
                     .Where(e => e.Attribute("mtype").Value == "seg")
                     .Select(item => (XElement)item.Parent.Parent.PreviousNode)
                         .Where(item => item != null)
                         .Select(item => item.Elements(xmlns + "source")
                             .Where(itema => itema != null)
                             .Select(itemb => itemb.Elements(xmlns + "x")             
                             .LastOrDefault()
                             .Attribute("id")
                             .Value.ToString())).ToArray();
```

What it does is that it locates a `mrk` tag (that has `@mtype="seg"`) and then it goes up to the `trans-unit` ancestor (.parent.parent) and checks if the previous sibling `trans-unit` has a child `trans` and if not, it returns from the `source` child the `@id` of the last `x` element, otherwise it returns `null` (it must return null, cannot just not return match).

I need to add that while the below samples only have one such previous node with no `trans` element, in the real life xml there are many more, so I must use `PreviousNode`.

Here is the XML it works with, and returns `"2"` perfectly:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xliff xmlns:sdl="http://sdl.com/FileTypes/SdlXliff/1.0" version="1.2" sdl:version="1.0" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
  <file original="Pasadena_Internet_2016.xml" source-language="en-US" datatype="x-sdlfilterframework2" target-language="da-DK">
    <body>
      <trans-unit id="d679cb2d-ecba-47ba-acb7-1bb4a798c755" translate="no">
        <source>
          <x id="0" />
          <x id="1" />
          <x id="2" />
        </source>
      </trans-unit>
      <trans-unit id="aed9fde2-fd1b-4eba-bfc9-06d325aa7047">
        <source>
          <x id="3" />Pasadena, California’s iconic Colorado Boulevard <x id="4" />has been the site of the world-famous Tournament of Roses Parade since it began in 1890.
        </source>
        <seg-source>
          <mrk mtype="seg" mid="1">
            <x id="3" />Pasadena, California’s iconic Colorado Boulevard <x id="4" />has been the site of the world-famous Tournament of Roses Parade since it began in 1890.
          </mrk>
        </seg-source>
        <target>
          <mrk mtype="seg" mid="1">
            <x id="3" /><x id="4" />Pasadena, Californiens ikoniske Colorado Boulevard har været stedet for den verdensberømte Rose Bowl-parade siden den begyndte i 1890.
          </mrk>
        </target>
      </trans-unit>
    </body>
  </file>
</xliff>
```

The problem is that I need to solve as a last step is that there is another type of XML that has the staring `trans-unit` encapsulated within another `group` element that is not present in the other XML. So here there is one more parent to jump upwards and get the previous `trans-unit` sibling, right before the `group`.

I am trying to build this into the same LINQ expression so it handles both scenarios.

In fact if I modify the line 6 to this, then it works:

```
.Select(item => (XElement)item.Parent.Parent.Parent.PreviousNode)
<!--                                        ^------ additional Parent -->
```

Here is the other XML that right now throws an exception with the above code, but it should return `"0"`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xliff xmlns:sdl="http://sdl.com/FileTypes/SdlXliff/1.0" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2" version="1.2" sdl:version="1.0">
  <file original="Internet_Anti-DrugIntro2015.xml_1457007.xlf" datatype="x-sdlfilterframework2" source-language="en-US" target-language="hu-HU">
    <body>
      <trans-unit translate="no" id="c3a13bfb-ed51-49cf-8278-e2c86c2114c0">
        <source>
          <x id="0"/>
        </source>
      </trans-unit>
      <group>
        <sdl:cxts>
          <sdl:cxt id="1"/>
        </sdl:cxts>
        <trans-unit id="3b4520df-4483-4c9e-8a9b-ce2544269f3e">
          <source>
            <x id="1"/>
          </source>
          <seg-source>
            <mrk mtype="seg" mid="2">
              <x id="1"/>Drugs are robbing our children of their future.
            </mrk>
            <mrk mtype="seg" mid="3">
              <x id="2"/>Every 17 seconds a teenager experiments with an illicit drug for the first time.
            </mrk>
          </seg-source>
          <target>
            <mrk mtype="seg" mid="2">
              <x id="1"/>A drogok megfosztják gyermekeinket a jövőjüktől.
            </mrk>
            <mrk mtype="seg" mid="3">
              <x id="2"/>17 másodpercenként egy újabb tizenéves próbálja ki először a kábítószereket.
            </mrk>
          </target>
        </trans-unit>
      </group>
      <trans-unit translate="no" id="7890462c-edcb-4fe6-9192-033ba76d9942">
        <source>
          <x id="183"/>
        </source>
      </trans-unit>
    </body>
  </file>
</xliff>
```

I will be more than appreciative for any help.

Comment: Try this :                              .Where(itema => (itema != null) && (itemb.Elements(xmlns + "x") != null) )

Comment: @jdweng -- I guess you meant `itema` not `itemb` this does not exist in the scope. While this prevents the exception, it does not return "0" as it should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of navigating up the XML tree using `Parent` several times depending on the XML structure, you can try using `Ancestors().Last()` to find the highest level ancestor named either `"trans-unit"` or `"group"`, and then navigate to the previous node.

Try to replace this part :

```
.Select(item => (XElement) item.Parent.Parent.PreviousNode)
```

with this one :

```
.Select(item => (XElement)item.Ancestors()
                              .Last(o => new[]{"trans-unit","group"}.Contains(o.Name.LocalName))
                              .PreviousNode)
```

Comment: OK, thanks. I tried this (both `new[]{"trans-unit","group"}` and `new[]{"group","trans-unit"}` but in the next line `.Where(item => item != null)` the value of item is `<sdl:cxts>`, which is below the `group`, so it seems that the first `trans-unit` is taken as the match and then its `PreviousNode` is matched, instead of going up to `group` and then match the `PreviousNode` of that.

Comment: @ib11 my bad, I thought it would be either `trans-unit` or `group` that exist at a time, didn't notice that `group` is actually parent of `trans-unit`. In this case, try using `Last()` instead of `First()`